How to change the values in navbar without refresh based on the 'user' which is maintained in a pinia store vue js 3?
I have a sidenavbar which has list of items say
Home
Update
Delete
Restart
I have 2 users say admin and staff.
Home page displays by default and doesn't require any login. Once the user clicks on login button in Dashboard and logs in, I have the user state maintained in store using pinia.
When there is admin login, I want to hide 'Update' from the navbar list and have only
Home
Delete
Restart
When there is staff login, I want to hide 'Delete' from the navbar list and have only
Home
Update
Restart
But I don't see the value of the list getting changed in the UI based on the user state. However on refresh I can see the required change in UI.
Not revealing the exact code
Navbar.vue
This piece of code is preceeded with a for-loop from which I get the list of subpages and 'value' is the metadata from which a page is identified.
value:
home for Home
delete for Delete
update for Update
restart for Restart
Here I'm getting the name of the pages from the translation files which is   {{ $t(pages.${value}) }}  this piece of code
<template>
            <v-list-item v-if="(value !== 'update' && value !== 'delete')">
              <template>
                <p class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold text-caption">
                  {{ $t(`pages.${value}`) }} 
                </p>
              </template>
            </v-list-item>
            <v-list-item  v-else-if="(value == 'update' && username == 'admin ')">
              <template>
                <p class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold text-caption">
                  {{ $t(`pages.${value}`) }}
                </p>
              </template>
            </v-list-item>
            <v-list-item v-else-if="(value == 'delete' && username == 'staff')">
              <template>
                <p class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold text-caption">
                  {{ $t(`pages.${value}`) }}
                </p>
              </template>

</template>

<script>
import { useLoginStore } from '@/stores/loginStore'
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'

const { username } = storeToRefs(useLoginStore())
</script>

loginStore.ts:
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import LoginService from '@/services/LoginService'

export const useLoginStore = defineStore('login', () => {
 const user = ref(localStorage.getItem('user'))
 
   const username = computed(() => user.value)

  

  const login = async (username: string, password: string): Promise<void> => {
    try {
     .........
       Code for login api
     .............
      // Setting user state
      localStorage.setItem('user', username)
    } catch (err) {
      throw err
    } finally {
      .........
    }
  }

  }

 
  return {
    user,username
  }
})

This code gives me the required list but only on refresh. How can I see the change in the data of navbar immediately after user login?
Also, how to optimise the code block having v-if, v-else-if?

localStorage is not reactive. you have to set user.value also. the localStorage value is used only once when store is created.

@IgorMoraru Could you pls post the corrected lines of code?

In login function, after localStorage.setItem('user', username) add user.value = username

@IgorMoraru It works! Need a clarification in this. Doesn't this part,  const username = computed(() => user.value) take care of the changed value in localStorage?

No, because like I wrote, localStorage is not reactive, so Vue cannot detect changes in its value. the value from localStorage is used only to initialize the user ref (when the store is created). as long as you don't change the value of user ref, the computed username will not be reevaluated.
